# How to use UseNodeModules in ASP.Net Core 3?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, nuget

I follow this [tutorial](https://app.pluralsight.com/library/courses/aspnet-core-fundamentals) about ASP.NET Core in Pluralsight.

It uses a package named [OdeToCode.UseNodeModules](https://github.com/OdeToCode/UseNodeModules) but when I used it in "Startup.cs", I got this:

> Argument 2: cannot convert from 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IWebHostEnvironment' to 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment'  OdeToFood

[Screenshot of the code and error in my project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXt1v.jpg)

---

You can see the usage of the package in the code below. The error refers to that "environment" parameter of UseNodeModules.

```
public class Startup
{
    // ...

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment environment)
    {
        // ...

        app.UseNodeModules(environment);

        // ...
    }
}
```

You see, That "IHostingEnvironment" above is an obsolete type now. It is "IWebHostEnvironment" in my project. But even when I use the obsolete types, I still get that error.

---

So, I want to know the solution. How can I use this package in 3?
If there is no way, Please kindly show me an alternate way. I am a greenhorn.

Comment: Did [this](https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/10/07/usenodemodules-updated-for-net-core-3.aspx) resolve your issue?No need to pass enviroment,you could refer to the [source code](https://github.com/OdeToCode/UseNodeModules/blob/master/src/OdeToCode.UseNodeModules/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs).

Comment: @Rena God. That took some tens of my hours and I just have had to remove that parameter, apparently. Thanks a lot. As I said, I am a greenhorn.

(Removing that parameter is the solution.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the [source code](https://github.com/OdeToCode/UseNodeModules/blob/master/src/OdeToCode.UseNodeModules/ApplicationBuilderExtensions.cs),it seems no need to pass the environment in asp.net core 3.x.

Reference:

https://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2019/10/07/usenodemodules-updated-for-net-core-3.aspx